Why is my Gouraud Shading not working correctly?
I am trying to write a 3d Renderer in C using SDL and cgml but my shading seems to be not working correctly. When rendering the teapot I get seams and when I want to render a cube I get a bright white line between my triangles. I am pretty sure that I calculate my normals correctly but I can show that code too if necessary. All my math functions like v3_normalise / cam_perspective should be correct too because they are just aliases for cgml functions.

static void _draw_triangle(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3) {
    SDL_RenderLine(renderer, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    SDL_RenderLine(renderer, x2, y2, x3, y3);
    SDL_RenderLine(renderer, x3, y3, x1, y1);
}

static int32_t _compare_triangles(const void* a, const void* b) {
    triangle_t* triangle_a = (triangle_t*)a;
    triangle_t* triangle_b = (triangle_t*)b;

    float z1 = (triangle_a->vertices[0].z + triangle_a->vertices[1].z + triangle_a->vertices[2].z) / 3.0f;
    float z2 = (triangle_b->vertices[0].z + triangle_b->vertices[1].z + triangle_b->vertices[2].z) / 3.0f;

    float comparison = z2 - z1;
    if (comparison < 0.0f) return 1;
    if (comparison > 0.0f) return -1;
    return 0;
}

static void _render_triangles_mesh(SDL_Renderer* renderer, triangle_t* triangles_to_render, size_t num_triangles_to_render) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF);  // set color to pink

    for (size_t j = 0; j < num_triangles_to_render; j++) {
        triangle_t triangle = dynamic_array_at(triangles_to_render, j);

        _draw_triangle(
            renderer,
            triangle.vertices[0].x, triangle.vertices[0].y, 
            triangle.vertices[1].x, triangle.vertices[1].y,
            triangle.vertices[2].x, triangle.vertices[2].y
        );
    }
}

static v3i _calc_vertex_color(v3 normal, v3 light_direction) {
    float intensity = glm_max(0.1f, v3_dot(normal, light_direction)) * 1.5f;
    v3i color = v3i_of((int32_t)glm_clamp(255.0f * intensity, 0.0f, 255.0f));

    return color;
}

static void _render_triangles_filled(SDL_Renderer* renderer, triangle_t* triangles_to_render, size_t num_triangles_to_render, v3* vertex_normals, v3 light_direction) {
    /* convert to SDL_Vertex triangles and add to vertices to render */
    SDL_Vertex vertices[num_triangles_to_render * 3];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_triangles_to_render; i++) {
        triangle_t triangle = dynamic_array_at(triangles_to_render, i);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            v3i color = _calc_vertex_color(vertex_normals[triangle.indices[j]], light_direction);

            /* add vertex to SDL vertices */
            SDL_Vertex vertex = {
                .position = {triangle.vertices[j].x, triangle.vertices[j].y}, 
                .color = {color.r, color.g, color.b, 0xFF}
            };
            vertices[i * 3 + j] = vertex;
        }
    }
        
    /* render triangles */
    SDL_RenderGeometry(renderer, NULL, vertices, num_triangles_to_render * 3, NULL, 0); 
}

int32_t render(state_t* state, mesh_t* mesh, v3 object_offset) {
    static float alpha = 0;
    alpha += 0.6f * state->time.delta_sec;

    m4 rotation_matrix = glms_euler_xyz(v3_of(0.0f, alpha, 0.0f)); // glms_euler_xyz(v3_of(alpha * 0.5f, 0.0f, alpha));
    m4 translation_matrix = glms_translate_make(object_offset);
    m4 world_matrix = m4_mul(translation_matrix, rotation_matrix);

    v3 up = v3_of(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    v3 target = v3_add(state->engine.camera.position, state->engine.camera.direction);
    m4 camera_matrix = cam_lookat(state->engine.camera.position, target, up);
    m4 view_matrix = glms_inv_tr(camera_matrix);
    
    triangle_t* triangles_to_render = dynamic_array_create(triangle_t);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < mesh->num_triangles; i++) {
        triangle_t triangle = dynamic_array_at(mesh->triangles, i);
        triangle_t triangle_transformed, triangle_projected, triangle_viewed;

        /* rotate and translate triangle */
        triangle_transformed = triangle;
        triangle_transformed.vertices[0] = m4_mulv(world_matrix, triangle.vertices[0]);
        triangle_transformed.vertices[1] = m4_mulv(world_matrix, triangle.vertices[1]);
        triangle_transformed.vertices[2] = m4_mulv(world_matrix, triangle.vertices[2]);
    
        /* world space to camera space */
        triangle_viewed = triangle_transformed;
        triangle_viewed.vertices[0] = m4_mulv(view_matrix, triangle_transformed.vertices[0]);
        triangle_viewed.vertices[1] = m4_mulv(view_matrix, triangle_transformed.vertices[1]);
        triangle_viewed.vertices[2] = m4_mulv(view_matrix, triangle_transformed.vertices[2]);

        /* 3d to 2d */
        triangle_projected = triangle_viewed;
        triangle_projected.vertices[0] = m4_mulv(state->engine.projection_matrix, triangle_viewed.vertices[0]);
        triangle_projected.vertices[1] = m4_mulv(state->engine.projection_matrix, triangle_viewed.vertices[1]);
        triangle_projected.vertices[2] = m4_mulv(state->engine.projection_matrix, triangle_viewed.vertices[2]);
        triangle_projected.vertices[0] = v4_divs(triangle_projected.vertices[0], triangle_projected.vertices[0].w);
        triangle_projected.vertices[1] = v4_divs(triangle_projected.vertices[1], triangle_projected.vertices[1].w);
        triangle_projected.vertices[2] = v4_divs(triangle_projected.vertices[2], triangle_projected.vertices[2].w);

        /* backface culling using winding order */
        v3 line1 = v3_sub(v3_from(triangle_projected.vertices[1]), v3_from(triangle_projected.vertices[0]));
        v3 line2 = v3_sub(v3_from(triangle_projected.vertices[2]), v3_from(triangle_projected.vertices[0]));
        float sign = line1.x * line2.y - line2.x * line1.y;
        if (sign > 0.0f) continue;
        
        /* scale into view */
        triangle_projected.vertices[0].x = map(triangle_projected.vertices[0].x, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0, WIDTH);
        triangle_projected.vertices[0].y = map(triangle_projected.vertices[0].y, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0, HEIGHT);
        triangle_projected.vertices[1].x = map(triangle_projected.vertices[1].x, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0, WIDTH);
        triangle_projected.vertices[1].y = map(triangle_projected.vertices[1].y, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0, HEIGHT);
        triangle_projected.vertices[2].x = map(triangle_projected.vertices[2].x, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0, WIDTH);
        triangle_projected.vertices[2].y = map(triangle_projected.vertices[2].y, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0, HEIGHT);
        
        /* add triangle to list */
        dynamic_array_append(triangles_to_render, triangle_projected);
    }

    /* transform vertex normals */
    v3* transformed_normals = malloc(sizeof(v3) * mesh->num_vertices);
    m3 normal_matrix = m3_inv(m4_pick3t(world_matrix));
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mesh->num_vertices; i++) {
        v3 normal = dynamic_array_at(mesh->vertex_normals, i);
        v3 normal_transformed = v3_normalize(m3_mulv(normal_matrix, normal));
        transformed_normals[i] = normal_transformed;
    }

    /* sort triangles back to front */
    size_t num_triangles_to_render = dynamic_array_get_length(triangles_to_render);
    qsort(triangles_to_render, num_triangles_to_render, sizeof(triangle_t), _compare_triangles);

    /* draw triangles */
    #ifdef DEBUG
        _render_triangles_mesh(state->renderer, triangles_to_render, num_triangles_to_render);
    #else
        _render_triangles_filled(state->renderer, triangles_to_render, num_triangles_to_render, transformed_normals, state->engine.light.direction);
    #endif
    
    /* cleanup */
    free(transformed_normals);
    dynamic_array_destroy(triangles_to_render);

    return state->retval;
}

EDIT: Image of the normals


"I am pretty sure that I calculate my normals correctly" - a fast way to check is to render line segments along the normals.

@Pikalek I checked and in my untrained eye they look correct and they are also all normalized

1 - All cubes corner normals seem to be skewed due to different number of triangles meeting in each corner (4 or 6), biasing them to different directions.

The sharp line you see at the triangle boundary of the cube is a Mach band. Four outward-splayed normals around the corners of a square would need a non-linear function to interpolate them, but interpolation inside a triangle is restricted to linear interpolation. So each triangle gets its own linear gradient, piecewise approximating the non-linear function, with a fold in the middle where the gradient direction changes. It's that change in rate of change we perceive as a line, even though there's no sudden brightening there.

So: the cube example is "as good as you can expect" with Gouraud shading, unless you subdivide the cube to approximate the non-linear curve more closely with more, smaller segments. You can see similar artifacts along diagonal edges in the torus example at the top of the Wikipedia article on the technique. That doesn't explain what's happening with the teapot example, though.

@DMGregory Thank you very much for your explaination, now I  just need to figure out whats up with the teapot!

For the cube, you can model each face of the cube so that they have their own normals perpendicular to their own triangle instead of averaging. This will give flat lighting across the whole face from directional lighting.
